# Futures: set result from a different thread

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio, coroutine

I have an http server that receives some requests in a thread. This http server parses the received data and sends part of the data to a different process.

The response from this process may take some time and is received on a callback in a different thread.

The issue here is that I need part of the response received in the callback function to respond to the initial request I received, so my idea was to use an asyncio.Task for this

My code is as follows:

```
my_futures = dict()

class HTTPHandler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandle):
    do_POST(self):
        #parse data
        asyncio.create_task(self.send_response())

    async def send_response(self):
        global my_futures
        my_futures[uuid] = asyncio.get_event_loop().create_future()
        send_data_to_processB()
        await my_future
        self.send_response()

# Callback where I receive the result from process B
def on_message(message):
    global my_futures
    my_futures[message['uuid']].set_result(message['result'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = http.server.HTTPServer(LISTEN_ADDR, MyHTTPHandler)
    threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever).start()
    processB.register_callback(on_message)
```

The problem with this approach is that the task is not being executed and the callback does not receive results at all.

I also tried changing the `do_POST` method to use `asyncio.run(self.send_response())` instead of `asyncio.create_task`, using this approach my callback gets the results and sets the result but the coroutine just hangs at `await my_future`

How can I achieve this task?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To interact with asyncio from outside the event loop thread, use `call_soon_threadsafe`:

```
def on_message(message):
    # my_loop must have been initialized from the main thread
    my_loop.call_soon_threadsafe(
        my_futures[message['uuid']].set_result, message['result'])
```

Instead of `create_task`, call `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe`.

However, this is not the only problem with your code. You are never *running* the event loop, so none of this has a chance to execute. You need to have `asyncio.run` or equivalent somewhere in your code, typically at top-level.

Since `HTTPServer` is not written for asyncio, you cannot call asyncio functions from `do_POST`. Instead, look into using [`aiohttp`](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp).

Answer (score 5):

Same as above, but without the need to save a reference to the event loop

```
future = my_futures[message['uuid']]
result = message['result']
future.get_loop().call_soon_threadsafe(future.set_result, result)
```